# OpenSSL / LibreSSL issue on Mac - dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: mysql, macos, openssl, dylib, wp-cli

I did a brew update && brew upgrade to try and fix a problem (stoopid!!) and now I get various forms of:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql
  Reason: image not found
```

For example when I execute

```
wp config create
```

From this [GitHub page](https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86), I've tried a variety of brew uninstall and resinstall of openssl, openssl@1.1, etc, but I can't work out what's not updating.

I know I've had problems in the past trying to work out the difference between the Mac php and the MAMP php ... perhaps there's a similar problem here and I'm not updating the correct one ...

I don't know how to change the version that /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql (see error above) is pointing to.

Any wisdom appreciated!!

I'm on Mac OS Catalina with MAMP Pro running Apache and MySQL:
MySQL - Server version: 5.7.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Apache - Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.2
PHP version: 7.4.2

Comment: PS: ... $ which php
/usr/local/bin/php ...
$ which mysql
/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql

Comment: And: ... $ openssl version  LibreSSL 2.8.3